# How to change image name by timestamp in Database realtime after down url from storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I already push the image to `Firebase storage` successfully, but I have a problem that. The images pushed onto `Storage` then get url to Firebase DB keep, it `duplicating names`, the new one overwrites the old. Now, I want to `change it back to` the `current timestamp` instead of the image name pushed onto it `change the name image in DB to name image plus timestamp`. To image not repeat. I mean, every time I push the image name then in DB will be replaced by the current time the image was pushed when they down URL

How can I do that in the code below

```
export const createProduct = async (productData, image) => {
  const uploadTask = await firebaseStorage
    .ref(`/images/${image.name}`)
    .put(image);
  if (uploadTask.state === "success") {
    const url = await firebaseStorage
      .ref("images")
      .child(image.name)
      .getDownloadURL();
    const result = {
      ...productData,
      image: url,
    };
    const postRef = firebaseDb.ref("products").push();
    return postRef
      .set(result)
      .then(() => {
        return getProducts();
      })
      .catch(() => ({ status: "error" }));
  }
  return { status: "failure" };
};
```

My code above is pushing the image first and then get the URL to the Firebase database.  Then get status if is push success or not

Please, anyone can help me? thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to name every image after the timestamp on the client that uploads it, that'd be:

```
const uploadTask = await firebaseStorage
  .ref(`/images/${Date.now()}`)
  .put(image);
```

---

To change the property name under which you store the URL in the database, you could do something like:

```
const url = await firebaseStorage
  .ref("images")
  .child(image.name)
  .getDownloadURL();
const name = 'image_'+Date.now();
const result = {
  ...productData,
  [name]: url,
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try it

Comment: I am sorry, I have updated my question above. I mean replace image name in Firebase Database realtime. Not in storage. Can you help me with that? Thank you so much

Comment: I added an example of that too.

Comment: I include Date.now () for both storage and DB right

Comment: It's also duplicate name of image in DB. Example, I make push my image is name `pudding.png` in Storage is also name `pudding but has add more name like pudding_timestamp.png` to be different if I push the same image in onto storage and then in DB like this also like that.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself based on the two snippets I gave you?

Comment: Yes, Idid, I already. But it's doesn't work. My leader has said that, I need to create an constants for that then add to image ref. That mean change image name, ref by timestamp. But not done directly but indirectly. I should create constants for ref.

Comment: It still duplicate name in DB

Comment: As you updated just change image field name, not image name. I mean , I changed the url name. when it push on Storage and in DB. `const name = 'image_'+Date.now();
const result = {
  ...productData,
  [name]: url,
};` Not [name]:url, not Change name of field, the name change is url is will be change image name in here by `timestamp`. Hope you understand my explain

Comment: Not changing the field name, but changing the name of the image according to timestamp. That is how the image name on the storage, the DB side will get the image name like storage. Hope you understand my explain. Thank you so much for help me

Comment: There are two values you can modify here as far as I can see: the name of the file in Storage, and the name of the field in which you store the download URL. You can't modify the download URL itself - as that is generated by Firebase.